# requirejs knockout and mustache - how to inject symbols in script scope?

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, mustache, amd

I trying to build a colored chess game app using : requirejs, jquery, knockout and mustache for templating.

I found on github and script to extend knockout's templating system with mustache, but I couldn't integrate it cleanly in my code. This script assumes that 'ko' symbol is yet defined inside it (it's a kind of plugin) but I get a reference error : 'ko' is not defined...

I have the following directory layout :

```
project/
  www/
    index.html
    js/
      app.js
      app/
        colorchess.js
        ui.js
      libs/
        jquery.js
        ko-min.js
        ko.mustache.js
        mustache.js
        require.js
```

and the following JS files :

-- app.js --

```
requirejs.config({

baseUrl : "js/app",
paths : {
    "app" : "./app",
    "jquery" : "../lib/jquery",
    "ko" : "../lib/ko-min",
    "mustache" : "../lib/mustache",
    "ko.mustache" : "../lib/ko.mustache"
},
shim : {
    'ko.mustache' : ['ko', 'mustache']
}
});

requirejs(["colorchess"]);
```

-- colorchess.js --

```
require(['ui'], function() {

   ... main game logic ...

})
```

-- ui.js --

```
define(['jquery', 'ko'], function(jquery, ko) {
    console.log(ko);

            // BUG HERE (in this require)
    require(['ko.mustache'], function() {

        console.log('ko.mustache');

    });
```

});

So my question definitly is : how to make 'ko' symbol global to 'ko.mustache.js' script scope and fix the ReferenceError bug ?

Regards

Comment: I am not familiar with the `ko.mustache` script, but did you try doing : `window.ko = ko;` before your `require['ko.mustache']` call?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ko.mustache` expects `ko` to be available in a global namespace. And when using RequireJS their are not exposed to a global, but returned as modules and passed as a reference.

1. Wrap ko.mustache into define with dependency to `ko` and `mustache`. Then you will not need shim. Which is much cleaner.
2. Expose ko and mustache as global variables before calling require on `ko.mustache`:

Sample:

```
define(['jquery', 'ko', 'mustache'], function (jquery, ko, mustache) {
    console.log(ko);

    window.ko = ko;
    window.Mustache = mustache;

    require(['ko.mustache'], function () {  console.log('ko.mustache'); });
});
```

Comment: must 'ko' and 'mustache' attached to global scope ? Is it not a kind of nmespace pollution ? I place a console.log(this); in ko.mustache script, but I get a "Object window" as a result... I prefer not to alter my vendor/tier scripts, of course ! thanks for your answer, Tomas.

Comment: You need to get job done right? In this case, modify vendor script or implement hack/workaround to work with it. Or request vendor to implement AMD support.

Comment: making other attempts with IcanHaz.js (a nice Mustache wrapper) I have coded a module to wrap (again) IChanHaz (a.k.a. ich)...  just export window.ich as the return value of the module and it works ;-)